# Linux Firewall & sharing files between computers in different subnets connected to single switch

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, linux-networking, iproute2

EDIT : I've edited the question & the title to bring more clarity hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

```
           *************************
           * Internet Modem/Router *    
           *    192.168.1.1        *
           *************************
                     *                   
                     *    
                     *  192.168.1.2(eth0)
           *************************
           *    Linux Firewall     *  
           ************************* 
                    *   192.168.2.1(eth1) , 192.168.3.1(eth1:0) <--- (Virtual Interface)
                    *
                    *
                    *
           *************************       ***********
           *        Switch         * * * * * Router  ********** 192.168.0.x network.
           *************************       ***********
           *                      *         10.0.0.200
           *                      *
           *                      *
           *                      *
           *                      *
         * * * *                * * * *
         * PC  *                * PC  *
         * * * *                * * * *

    IP:192.168.2.10          IP: 192.168.3.10
  Gateway: 192.168.2.1      Gateway: 192.168.3.1
```

Gateway's of both the networks i.e  192.168.2.0/24 and  192.168.3.0/24
computers are both residing in the Linux firewall machine namely
192.168.2.1(eth1) , 192.168.3.1(eth1:0 -Virtual Interface).

Note: Computers in 192.168.2.0/24 and  192.168.3.0/24 network are both
connected to a single switch.

1. The computers in the 192.168.2.0/24 network and the computers in the 192.168.3.0/24 network should be able to share files with each other, ping, ssh etc.
2. Machines from 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.3.0/24 accessing machines in 192.168.0.x network, packets of the same should be sent to the router 10.0.0.200.

> sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
>   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
>
> iptables -L
>   Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.2         tcp spts:login:65535 dpt:ssh >state NEW,ESTABLISHED
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.2         tcp spts:login:65535 dpt:ndmp >state NEW,ESTABLISHED
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level warning
>   DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.2          anywhere            tcp spt:ssh dpts:login:65535 state ESTABLISHED
>   ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.2          anywhere            tcp spt:ndmp dpts:login:65535 state ESTABLISHED
>   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> ## Machine: 192.168.2.10
>
> Active Routes:
>   Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
>            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1    192.168.2.10       10
>          127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
>        192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.2.10    192.168.2.10       10
>       192.168.2.12  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10
>      192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.2.10    192.168.2.10       10
>          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.2.10    192.168.2.10       10
>    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.2.10    192.168.2.10       1
>
> ## Default Gateway:       192.168.2.1
>
> Persistent Routes:
>    None
>
> ## Machine: 192.168.3.10
>
> Active Routes:
>   Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
>            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.10       10
>          127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
>        192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0     192.168.3.10    192.168.3.10       10
>       192.168.2.12  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       10
>      192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.3.10    192.168.3.10       10
>          224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0     192.168.3.10    192.168.3.10       10
>    255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255     192.168.3.10    192.168.3.10       1
>
> ## Default Gateway:       192.168.3.1
>
> Persistent Routes:
>      None

For much easier reading the output of the above commands is available at Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/aVHRvGEE)

I've read [LARTC](http://www.lartc.org/howto/) but frankly it's intimidating at this point. I am a little short of knowledge/information on where to begin. Any inputs in pointing me in the right direction will help.

Comment: Post the output of:  sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward & iptables -L on the linux box, and route print on the two windows guests.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Output of the commands you requested [link](http://pastebin.com/aVHRvGEE) @MichaelHampton To be honest, I have checked/read Linux policy based routing without any luck of how to proceed. Any input in the right direction is much appreciated !

Comment: Why do you have two separate subnets for your PCs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know it's silly but administrators at work want separation of IP addresses for documentation w.r.t the Linux firewall which also runs Squid in Transparent mode. Based on the network, policies w.r.t web filtering have been configured in Squid.

Comment: OK, well, the thing that's still missing from your question is: what's broken?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well 2 things, 1. Machines from 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 should be able to share files, ping, ssh. This isn't working right now. 2. Any machine from 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.3.0/24 network accessing 192.168.0.x, packets should be sent to 10.0.0.200. This doesn't & will not work by default. I am unsure how to proceed to setup the routing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need several fixes:

- All the 192.168.2.0/24 machines need a network route out their interface for the 192.168.3.0/24 machines -- and vice versa.
- All the 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 machines need a host route for 10.0.0.200 out their interface.
- All the 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 machines need a network route for 192.168.0.0/24 via the 10.0.0.200 address.
- All the 192.168.0.0/24 machines need a host route for 10.0.0.200 out their interface.
- All the 192.168.0.0/24 machines need a default route of 10.0.0.200.

I might have overlooked one of the pieces, there's a lot of pieces here.